# Spring boot mapstruct mapper using other mapper

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

Is it possible to use different mappers in mapstruct?
e.g. I have this mapper

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ObjMapperImpl implements ObjMapper{
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public ObjDto daoToDto(Obj obj) {
        return ObjDto.builder()
                .meetLink(obj.getMeetLink())
                .date(obj.getFromDate().toLocalDate())
                .user(userMapper.daoToDto(obj.getUser()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change this implementation to mapstruct?

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work for you, the generated implementation of daoToDto() of ObjMapper will invoke daoToDto() of UserMapper, you only need to specify the mapping from `fromDate` to `date` due to property name difference.

```java
@Mapper(component Model = "spring")
public class ObjMapper{

    @Mapping(source = "fromDate", target = "date")
    ObjDto daoToDto(Obj obj);
}
```

Comment: You should probably add `component Model = "spring")` for the component annotation.

Comment: @Huu Phuong Vu thanks for adding solution for date but what about it `.user(userMapper.daoToDto(obj.getUser()))`

Comment: @MateuszSobczak that will be handled by MapStruct, the generated `daoToDto()` of `ObjMapperImpl` will invoke `daoToDto()` of `UserMapperImpl`.

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct has an entire section about [Invoking other mappers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers) in the documentation.

When you want to use other mappers in your mapper you need to use `Mapper#uses`.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = UserMapper.class)
public class ObjMapper{

    @Mapping(source = "fromDate", target = "date")
    ObjDto daoToDto(Obj obj);
}
```